# Unable to install Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am following the installation guide on Docker for Ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

I have downloaded the Ubuntu deb file, when i run Docker Desktop, it shows the following error:
[image]

I also tried Setting up and installing Docker Engine from Docker’s apt repository.

I ran this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
```

I have the following unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-desktop : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: pass but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: uidmap
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do i download Docker, either from Docker Desktop or from the apt's repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the packages of the unmet depencies first:

- qemu-system-x86
- docker-ce-cli
- pass
- uidmap

Install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install NAMEOFPACKAGE
```

In addition you can run following command to fix broken or missing depencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

OR

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Maybe an update / upgrade could be helpful

```
apt update & apt-upgrade
```